# IOS:string split of date

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a date in the format: `22-10-2013` and
I want to show the date in the pdf as `22-10, 2013`.
In the pdf only it is shown as `-----,20--`.
I have to fill the date in the blank spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:"dd-MM, yyyy"];

NSString *dateString= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];
```

With this you can specify your format you want to output, it will output:
`22-10, 2013` exactly as you wanted.

Apply this:

```
[DrawPdf drawString:[NSString StringWithFormat:@"Issued in Columbia, Missouri on %@.", dateString] OfFont:12 atRect:CGRectMake(currentX, currentPageY, 500, 20)];
```

Comment: But in my pdf it is given as this ----------,20----.

Comment: In this blank spaces the date must come up

Comment: @Houssni it is like this

Comment: [DrawPdf drawString:@"Issued in Columbia, Missouri on _________________________ , 20____." OfFont:12 atRect:CGRectMake(currentX, currentPageY, 500, 20)];

Comment: @Houssni In the blank spaces,I have to populate the value of date from database

Comment: @debina Edited my answer, try it out.

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,

```
           NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
           NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:@"22-10-2013"];
              [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM,yyyy"];
           NSString*  output = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

O/P:-`22-10,2013`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM,yyyy"];
NSString *result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```